# What is the next method after 3-style in 3x3 Blindfolded?

Tags: rubiks-cube, algorithm, mechanical-puzzles, twisty-puzzles

I have been using the method 3-style for over 2 years,

[3-style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bq9oz1k5wP4)

and I have settled in the range of 25-30 seconds. I wish to permanently become sub-20, and for that I am planning to undertake the uphill task of making, profiling and learning, and getting mastery in the 5-style method for both edges and corners of a 3x3 Rubik's cube.

[5-style method explanation and genesis in Spanish](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AP7bWc4HksycymmnyCb4Kb370FwfqsciPdNDgLITlX4/edit?usp=sharing)

A visual picture of how one 5-style algorithm will affect the cube:
A total of just 5 algorithms will solve any normal 20 target 3x3 scramble.

The useful tools of edge swapping, and doing many kinds of parity algorithm remains the same, as it can be used even in the case of a 5-style solve, near the completion of the cube.

[image: 5 edges getting switched by the algorithm: U D M B' U' S R' S' R U B M' U' D']

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: The question is asking what will be the successor method to the 3-style. It is not expected to be an open ended answer , but just an extrapolation of the current methods.

Answer (score 1):

The "next method" is not going to be 5-style. Full 5-style is not humanly possible, as the amount of memorisation required is far too great. Even the people with the biggest algorithm knowledge know "only" a few thousand algorithms, and 5-style edges is $22 \times 20 \times 18 \times 16 = 126,720$ cases. That's 35 new cases a day for 10 years. Creating solutions on the fly is not going to be fast either. That would be hard enough with 3-style. Also, learning a subset of 5-style would be pointless, as all the cases would arise too rarely.

The most recent developments have for the most part been extensions of 3-style. "Floating buffers" is a common thing among top solvers, where you switch to another buffer when your main buffer gets solved. People also learn 2e2e and 2c2c cases (i.e. 2 edge-2 edge swaps and 2-corner 2-corner swaps) to avoid unnecessary cycle breaking. If you're reading this question wondering what to learn next after 3-style, it's these things, as well as learning a wider range of parity cases and flips/twists.

So what's next as far as method development goes? It's hard to say. A lot of top BLD solvers have been secretive of their progess in the past so who knows what's currently being developed behind the scenes. With people learning speed-focused algs for every 3-cycle on the cube, the next step will likely involve (a) improving pre-existing 3-cycle algs and (b) working on improving 2c2c/2e2e. If you can save .2 on every alg, that's 2 seconds of time save. Newer alg sets will always have more room for improvement than old ones, so this is likely to be a source of improvement in the near future.

Comment: I agree with you. Floating buffer, floating 2-flip and full parity are already pretty advanced 3-style sets. 5-style is more feasible than ever now, since its my 6th year that I am working on it and nearing completion. Only drilling recog and recall time for the 126k 3x3 edge algs remain, which should be easy with the bluetooth cube trainer code I have written.

Comment: There are still more possibilities being explored, and as more people are pushing the blind theory ahead, we will be having resources like 5-style accessible to the newer cubers as well. Every algset seems daunting at first.